# Record User Activity On Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

Is there a program that I can use that will record the activity of each user (even if they are using the server simultaneously) so I can review and retain for posterity?  The server setup is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=925100

And if it's an EXCHANGE server, try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508855(EXCHG.65).aspx

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to just post links to other sites as an answer, Serverfault is aiming to be the repository of answers to questions, as such it is best to try and summarise the answers you may have found else where and then ensure you add a link accrediting the original source.